# Javascript dynamic table, droppable fires twice

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-droppable

I made a table via JS, with droppable divs inside a cell. If i drop an element into it, tge drop function fires twice. (See console). I guess it gas to do with for loop...

*Jsbin*: http://jsbin.com/OMIbOGU/50/edit

**JS**

```
$("document").ready(function(){

  function init(){
    var table = $("<table></table>");
    $("body").append(table);
    for(var i=0 ;i < 9; i++){
      var row = $("<tr></tr>");
      var cell =  $("<td></td>");
      for(var j = 0;j<2;j++){
        var slot = $("<div></div>").addClass('slot');

        slot.droppable({
          accept: ".unassigned",
          tolerance: "touch",
          drop:function(){
            console.log("dropped");
          }
        });

        if (j!==1)
          slot.addClass("dotted");
        cell.append(slot);
      }
      row.append(cell);    
      table.append(row);

    }

    $(".unassigned").draggable({
      revert: "invalid",
      snap: "td div"
    });
  }

  for(var k = 0 ; k<4;k++)
    init();
});
```

Comment: where is console here..?

Answer (score 0):

Usually, initializing the droppable function with greedy:true must do the trick.
But unfortunately it didn't worked for me either.
So I used the parameters passed in callback function drop and the global event number from that parameter.

```
$("document").ready(function(){
  guid=0;
  function init(){
    var table = $("<table></table>");
    $("body").append(table);
    for(var i=0 ;i < 9; i++){
      var row = $("<tr></tr>");
      var cell =  $("<td></td>");
      for(var j = 0;j<2;j++){
        var slot = $("<div></div>").addClass('slot');

        slot.droppable({
          accept: ".unassigned",
          tolerance: "touch",
          drop:function(lev,lui){
            if(guid != lev.handleObj.guid)
              {
                console.log("dropped");
                guid = lev.handleObj.guid;
              }
          }
        });

        if (j!==1)
          slot.addClass("dotted");
        cell.append(slot);
      }
      row.append(cell);    
      table.append(row);

    }

    $(".unassigned").draggable({
      revert: "invalid",
      snap: "td div"
    });
  }

  for(var k = 0 ; k<4;k++)
    init();
});
```

So its fine I hope...

Answer (score -1):

Looks like caused by tolerance: "touch", try this

Javascript

```
slot.droppable({
    accept: ".unassigned",
    tolerance: "pointer",//changed "touch" -> "pointer"
    drop:function(){
        console.log("dropped");
    }
});
```

Or add more space between drop target divs, to not "touch" neighbours